# My component keeps rerendering while using a path param

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use a path param which I fetch from the URL path as an ID for an entity which I'm trying to fetch. I've created a custom data fetching hook which triggers when either the path of the passed params change. I'm use useParams from react router dom to get the ID of the book from the URL.

Below is the component code:

```
const BookDetails: FC<BookDetailsProps> = () => {
  let { bookId } = useParams();

  const { response, loading, error } = useApi(`/books/v1/volumes/${bookId}`);

  return <Wrapper></Wrapper>;
};

export default BookDetails;
```

And below is my custom hook:

```
const useApi = (url: string, params = {}) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<AxiosResponse>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<AxiosError>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await api(url, { params: params });
      setResponse(result);
    } catch (err: any) {
      setError(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [url, params]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);

  return { response, error, loading, fetchData };
};

export default useApi;
```

Now when I use my API hook with a component which fetches data using the params object everything is fine. The component doesn't rerender and I just get the data, but for some reason when I use it with path params it goes off.

Does anyone know how I should proceed?

Comment: What are `params` in this example? The route path params, or the `params` argument for the `useApi` hook? Can you share an example usage that triggers the issue?

Comment: params is an object containing query params. When I try to fetch data using query params it works. But when I dynamically change the path param it keeps rerendering. The component code is an example of when the issue occurs.

Comment: So which "params" object are you referring to, specifically? The value returned by the `useParams` hook, or the second argument passed to the `useApi` hook, named `params`? What are the query params? How are you dynamically changing path params? See [mcve]. The `params` argument appears to be a new object reference each render if one isn't passed, so this will retrigger the `useEffect` hook any time the component rerenders for any reason. Perhaps that is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that when no `params` object is passed to the `useApi` hook

```
useApi(`/books/v1/volumes/${bookId}`)
```

The `params` argument is initialized to a default empty object value.

```
const useApi = (url: string, params = {}) => {
  ...
```

This causes the `params` variable to be a new object reference anytime the component rerenders for any reason and will retrigger the `useEffect` hook because `fetchData` will be a newly recomputed reference.

```
  ...

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await api(url, { params: params });
      setResponse(result);
    } catch (err: any) {
      setError(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [url, params]); // <-- params new reference

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]); // <-- fetchData becomes new reference

  ...
};
```

I suggest not initializing `param` and only provide a fallback value when calling the `api` function.

Example:

```
const useApi = (url: string, params) => { // <-- don't initialize
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<AxiosResponse>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<AxiosError>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await api(url, { params: params || {} }); // <-- provide fallback value
      setResponse(result);
    } catch (err: any) {
      setError(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [url, params]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);

  return { response, error, loading, fetchData };
};

export default useApi;
```

This way `params` will be an undefined value from render to render and not change shallow reference equality each render.

Comment: Thank you so much! Clear explanation, and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`params` gets a new object instance on each call so the dependency array in the `useCallback` will never be the same between different calls (you haven't pass a `params` argument to your `useApi`) and therefore the `useEffect` will be triggered on each render casing a re-render, hence the infinite rerendering